# Accessing self.request.get() from a Function in Python Webapp2 App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I am trying to DRY up my webapp2.RequestHandlers by moving POST variable fetching and validation out to a Function.

self.request.get doesnt work in the Function outside of the Handler.  How do I access the POST vars from a Function?

```
class my_form(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):      
        fieldvalidation('field1', 'string')

def fieldvalidation(fieldname, validationoptions):
   x = self.request.get(fieldname)  # <<< does not work outside of class my_form
   .......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass self or self.request to the function.

```
class my_form(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):      
        fieldvalidation(self.request)

def fieldvalidation(request):
   x = request.get(fieldname)  # <<< get the fieldname from the request object
```